# MySQL error Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    users.*,
    classes.*, 
    evaluation.student_id, 
    evaluation.class_id, 
    evaluation.chapter_title,
    (SELECT
        `score`
     FROM 
        `evaluation`
     WHERE 
        `class_id` = 1 
     AND 
        `id` 
     IN
        (SELECT 
            MAX(`id`)
         FROM
            `evaluation`
         WHERE
            `class_id` = 1
         GROUP BY
            `chapter_title`)
     GROUP BY
        `chapter_title`) 
     AS
        `score`,
     (SELECT
        `total_score`
      FROM
        `evaluation`
      WHERE
        `class_id` = 1
      AND
        `id`
      IN
        (SELECT 
            MAX(`id`)
         FROM
            `evaluation`
         WHERE
            `class_id` = 1
         GROUP BY
            `chapter_title`)
      GROUP BY
         `chapter_title`)
      AS
         `total_score`
      FROM
        (`evaluation`
      INNER JOIN
        `users`
      ON 
        evaluation.student_id=users.id)
      INNER JOIN
        `classes`
      ON
        evaluation.class_id=classes.id
      WHERE
        users.role='student'
      AND
        evaluation.class_id = 1
      AND
        evaluation.student_id = 8
```

But when I execute this query in phpmyadmin it displays a error message saying:

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Whats wrong in the query.Please help. Thanks in advance.

I have this tables:

users
[image]

classes
[image]

evaluation
[image]

In the evaluation table(last image).. I would only want to return a distinct chapter_title or a grouped chapter_title that has the highest id and has a student_id of 8.

I needed to use this query... but returns an error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that both of your queries return more than one record:

```
SELECT `score`
     FROM `evaluation`
     WHERE `class_id` = 1 
       AND `id` IN (SELECT  MAX(`id`)
                     FROM `evaluation`
                     WHERE `class_id` = 1
                     GROUP BY `chapter_title`)
     GROUP BY `chapter_title`;

SELECT `total_score`
      FROM `evaluation`
      WHERE `class_id` = 1
        AND `id` IN (SELECT  MAX(`id`)
                     FROM `evaluation`
                     WHERE `class_id` = 1
                     GROUP BY `chapter_title`)
      GROUP BY`chapter_title`;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eee0e/1)

I altered your query slightly to the following:

```
SELECT u.*,
    c.*, 
    e.student_id, 
    e.class_id, 
    e.chapter_title,
    (SELECT `score`
     FROM `evaluation` e1
     WHERE `class_id` = 1 
       AND e.id = e1.id
       AND `id` IN (SELECT  MAX(`id`)
                     FROM `evaluation`
                     WHERE `class_id` = 1
                     GROUP BY `chapter_title`)
     GROUP BY `chapter_title`)  AS`score`,
     (SELECT `total_score`
      FROM `evaluation` e1
      WHERE `class_id` = 1
        AND e.id = e1.id
        AND `id` IN (SELECT  MAX(`id`)
                     FROM `evaluation`
                     WHERE `class_id` = 1
                     GROUP BY `chapter_title`)
      GROUP BY`chapter_title`) AS `total_score`
FROM `evaluation` e
INNER JOIN `users` u
  ON e.student_id=u.id
INNER JOIN `classes` c
  ON e.class_id=c.id
WHERE u.role='student'
  AND e.class_id = 1
  AND e.student_id = 8
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92414/17)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `LIMIT 1` on all of your subqueries, to ensure only one value is returned.

**E.g.**

```
select users.*, classes.*, evaluation.student_id, evaluation.class_id, evaluation.chapter_title, (
        select `score`
        from `evaluation`
        where `class_id` = 1
            and `id` in (
                select MAX(`id`)
                from `evaluation`
                where `class_id` = 1
                group by `chapter_title`
                )
        group by `chapter_title`
        limit 1
        ) as `score`, (
        select `total_score`
        from `evaluation`
        where `class_id` = 1
            and `id` in (
                select MAX(`id`)
                from `evaluation`
                where `class_id` = 1
                group by `chapter_title`
                )
        group by `chapter_title`
        limit 1
        ) as `total_score`
from (
    `evaluation` inner join `users` on evaluation.student_id = users.id
    )
inner join `classes` on evaluation.class_id = classes.id
where users.role = 'student'
    and evaluation.class_id = 1
    and evaluation.student_id = 8
```

Comment: I only want to return a distinct chapter title with the highest id. but this query returns all the chapter title

Comment: As per your question title, I resolved the error in your query. As to the business logic, if you are having issues with that, post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [corrected fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92414/32):

```
SELECT
    users.*,
    classes.*,
    evaluation.student_id,
    evaluation.class_id,
    evaluation.chapter_title,
    evaluation.score,
    evaluation.total_score
 FROM
    evaluation
 INNER JOIN users
 ON
    evaluation.student_id=users.id
  INNER JOIN
    classes
  ON
    evaluation.class_id=classes.id
  WHERE
    users.role='student'
  AND
    evaluation.class_id = 1
  AND
    evaluation.student_id = 8
 AND
 EXISTS
    (SELECT
        *
     FROM
        evaluation
     WHERE
        class_id = 1
    HAVING MAX(id) = evaluation.id)
 GROUP BY
    chapter_title
```

Main changes:

1. Instead of `IN`, use `EXISTS` (should be faster since it won't need to return all of it's sub-rows);
2. Some subqueries weren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your `SELECT scores` subquery (first one) is returning more than one row. It's the only one where it's not used in an `IN()` clause, and its results are returned as a field in the parent query. Since it's "returning" to a field, it MUST result in a single value+single row result set.